# Get the median value of n columns on a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

[image]

From which a want to get the average row-wise of non zero columns.

E.G. for 
row 0: `(1303 + 1316 + 1322 + 1315)/4`
row 2: `(1632 + 1628 + 1609)/3`

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace` , from 0 to `np.nan`

```
df.replace(0,np.nan).mean(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` twice - all values by sum of `True`s processes like `1`:

```
df = df.sum(axis=1).div(df.ne(0).sum(1))
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(1997)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(1000,1000)))
#print (df)


In [60]: %timeit (df.replace(0,np.nan).mean(1))
1 loop, best of 3: 188 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit (df.sum(axis=1).div(df.ne(0).sum(1)))
10 loops, best of 3: 21.8 ms per loop
```